# Cannot remove git remote

Tags: git, github

Every time I use 'git init'. some old repos appear as origin

```
git remote -v       
origin  https://github.com/a.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/a.git (push)
```

I can't remove theme

```
git remote remove origin
fatal: Remote-Repository not found: 'origin'
```

I'm able to add new remotes

```
origin  https://github.com/a.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/a.git (push)
bucket  https://b@bitbucket.org/b.git (fetch)
bucket  https://b@bitbucket.org/b.git (push)
```

or

```
origin  https://github.com/a.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/a.git (push)
origin  https://b@bitbucket.org/b.git (fetch)
origin  https://b@bitbucket.org/b.git (push)
```

and remove 'b' if I like (in both cases), but it's not possible to remove 'a'

I tried to remove old global git files, tried set-url, removed the local repo ... none worked

Comment: Running `git init` in an *existing* repository won't change any existing settings. If you are creating a new empty repository, phd's answer is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a remote `origin` in your global git config. To verify:

```
git config --global --get-regexp ^remote.origin.
```

If the command returns at least `remote.origin.url` remove the remote from the global config:

```
git config --global --remove-section remote.origin
```